# Variations - Changed pagelayout doesn't change in variation page

Tags: 2013, page-layout, variations

I have variations set up with 2 labels,

- en-us (Source)
- sv-se

It all works as it should. Although if I change the page layout in the english page and publish and make sure to run the variation jobs. It still doesn't reflect the change of pagelayout.

Comment: Are other changes propagated for the same page? Are there any error messages in the variations log? In the past I've had pages break individually because GUIDs didn't match up.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this question? Is this an issue with SharePoint or was there a fix that needed to be applied?